# Pyomo: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__default_objective__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, solver, pyomo

This https://github.com/amianAA/ALNS has files written in python and pyomo with ALNS algorithm to optimise MINLP railroad network models (applied to Madrid's network). Everything works fine but i got error in this function:

```
def solveFO(instance):
    opt = SolverFactory(str(solver))
    results = opt.solve(instance, tee=True)
    instance.load(results)
    return float(results.Solution.Objective.__default_objective__['value'])
```

**Output and the error**:

```
Time creating the model: 11 minutos 20 segundos
Academic license - for non-commercial use only
Optimize a model with 62941 rows, 175536 columns and 564324 nonzeros
Variable types: 953 continuous, 174583 integer (3733 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+08]
  Objective range  [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range        [1e+00, 5e+02]
Presolve removed 46175 rows and 104643 columns
Presolve time: 2.62s
Presolved: 16766 rows, 70893 columns, 158005 nonzeros
Variable types: 0 continuous, 70893 integer (0 binary)

Deterministic concurrent LP optimizer: primal and dual simplex
Showing first log only...

Presolve removed 636 rows and 23 columns
Presolved: 16130 rows, 70870 columns, 154117 nonzeros

Presolve removed 11677 rows and 57179 columns

Root simplex log...

Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
   0    3.8005345e+11   4.118750e+02   2.291190e+08      5s
  26    5.0222580e+11   0.000000e+00   6.321933e+08      5s
Concurrent spin time: 0.00s

Solved with dual simplex

Root relaxation: objective 1.598284e+11, 7355 iterations, 2.48 seconds

  Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
  Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

*    0     0               0    1.598284e+11 1.5983e+11  0.00%     -    6s

Explored 0 nodes (7355 simplex iterations) in 6.09 seconds
Thread count was 2 (of 2 available processors)

Solution count 1: 1.59828e+11 

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 1.598283725288e+11, best bound 1.598283725288e+11, gap 0.0000%
Freed default Gurobi environment
WARNING: DEPRECATION WARNING: the Model.load() method is deprecated for
  loading solutions stored in SolverResults objects.  By default, results
  from solvers are immediately loaded into the original model instance.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ALNS.py", line 117, in <module>
  solref = solveFO(instance)
File "ALNS.py", line 35, in solveFO
  return float(results.Solution.Objective.__default_objective__['value'])
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__default_objective__'
```

Thanks in advance for any helping hands!

Comment: Thanks @eylianesc

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declared `model.obj = Objective()`, then you can use `value(model.obj)` to fetch the value of the objective,

Comment: Thanks @Qi Chen, please where exactly do you mean I should  use the value(model.obj), I'm a bit lost!

Comment: Instead of `float(results.Solution.Objective.__default_objective__['value'])`

Comment: Yeah! i did exactly that, I'd rather got a `value error`, perhaps there is no value to return. Couldn't what to be returned in the function had to have a relation with the result?

Comment: That's odd. Maybe try removing the `instance.load(results)` call, since that's been deprecated for a while.

Comment: Hi @Qi, i v dropped it still no improvement, I used the approved version `instance.solutions.load_from(results)`, yet it reports same error. I ran across several different ways to access the objective values, to no avail. pls kindly come to my aid

Comment: Try seeing what the output is from `model.obj.display()`, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks @Qi. model.obj.display() only gave the objective description but not the objective value: obj : Size=0, Index=None, Active=True Key : Active : Value. What I need is the value of the objective function from the results

Comment: The fact that you see `Size=0` means that the objective is not being generated properly.

Comment: Yea! But wasn't it as a result of the Abstractmodel() created, because up to that stage, an instance hasn't been generated to feed in the model, talk less of applying a solver. My thoughts though, I stand to be corrected!

Comment: Is the code on the Github page that you link still up to date? I notice that files were updated most recently last year.

Comment: Yeah! I have made few changes in the files. If you wont mind, i will zip and send them to your email. kindly write to my email **bunmalik11@gmail.com**

Comment: Hi Anas, as I do not run a personalized answer service, you're welcome to put the relevant files in a Gist and post it here, so that the Q&A remains part of the public record.

Comment: Yeah cool. You can view the files here (https://gist.github.com/bunmalik/664770a387e98261bdef11887b58ff4a). Thanks!

Comment: I'm at a conference, so I haven't had as much time to look at it, but just to be clear, I execute ALNS.py?

Comment: Hi Qi, I have finally found the solution here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48928108/pyomo-when-using-python-script-are-there-any-quick-ways-to-show-the-objective/51203061#51203061). I used `print(value(instance.obj)` and `instance.obj.expr()` and both worked for me.  I'll further run the rest of the codes to see if there may be other challenges. Thanks very much for your patient and time.

Comment: Good to hear. Best of luck.